# Get a timestamp when a database column value is changed

Tags: sql, oracle

Always good learning and sharing knowledge.

I have a database that has among other columns a column that allows for a status of a transaction.
This allows values like `created`, `picked`, `executed`.

`ID   Status`
`1    created`
`2    picked`
`3    executed`

On the user side, they just right click a transaction and can click `picked` or `executed` (since `created` is what is assigned on record creation).
Is it possible to capture the **timeframe** for when the transaction status changes for example from `picked` to `executed` and display it as part of the final view? How would I do this?

Comment: You can use a trigger for that. Google create trigger on update

Comment: Show us the ddl of the table and expected behaviour and outcome. Where you want to store the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please decide:

- Are there any direct write operation access to your table outside of stored procedures?
- Do you want to keep actual table and audit table full synchronized?

If you plan to do write actions from stored procedure only - just create new table and write audit operations immediately after each action. This is the most explicit option, because there aren't any hidden calls here. And both tables can be fully synchronized (if you wrap your statement into transaction)

If you want to fill main table and audit table in the same transaction, however insert/update/delete/merge are called from Java/.Net, etc., then you have to add trigger. Please [check here how it can be done](https://www.viralpatel.net/auditing-dml-oracle/).

If you can live with latency between main table and audit table, please check [FLASHBACK ARCHIVE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5009.htm#SQLRF20008) option. It works with Oracle Transaction Log and fills audit table with a small delay. However it works at the separate job, which means that insert/update/delete/merge operations aren't slow down, because of audit table (please note, that Oracle always have transaction log, e.g. you just add one more job to process it). So this is the fastest option.